# Data does not succeed from a JSON response with array and multiple objects on jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, rest

I'm currently trying to pick up data in JSON format with jQuery from the following link: http://localhost:8181/rest/stuff . This link shows me a array with multiple objects. When I try the following code:

```
function loadStuff() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8181/rest/stuff',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Success!');      
            },
             error: function() {
                 alert('error getting JSON about stuff');
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

It doesn't show "Success!", instead it gives me the error alert. while the link is working fine. I tried this with a couple of another JSON API's and it worked fine.

Edit (example of the JSON response from the link):

```
[
  {
    "id": "CHN",
    "country": "China",
    "continent": "Asia",
    "region": "Eastern Asia",
    "surface": 9572900,
    "population": 1277558000
  },
  {
     // Same object
     ...
     ...
     ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you get any alert, i.e. the error alert? Also, what back-end language are you using to handle the AJAX request?

Comment: Forgot to mention, yes I get the error.

Comment: My guess is that you are incorrectly treating the AJAX request in the back-end. Your js is sending a request to the url and is expecting a return variable in JSON format. However, without looking at the beck-end code, my guess is that the back-end function is not returning any variable or a variable that is not in a JSON format.

Comment: So, you're link is to `localhost`, which of course is local to your box, not something the rest of us can get to/see. I'm guessing what is returned is not valid JSON, or you're getting some other kind of response (e.g., 404 or 500). The [`error` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) actually takes three parameters, the last of which is the error returned. How about telling us what that is?

Comment: I added example code in the post. That is how the array with the object looks like.

Comment: The status of the JSON response is 200 when I look at XHR. I dont get any 404 or 500.

Comment: @Taplar unfortunately, that didn't succeed.

Comment: Do you know if the server is setting the content type to be application/json?  Because if the response is 200 this really feels like the case that you are returning invalid(or no) json and jquery is throwing an error when parsing it because either you told it it is json(dataType: 'json') or the content type is json so it will try to auto parse for you based on that too.

Comment: You could try changing the dataType to 'text' to force it to ignore any thing the server tells it and see if that starts going into the success.  That would be a definite sign that the json response is bad.

Comment: @Taplar changing it to text didn't change the result. And the content-type is just "application/json".

Comment: `dataType: 'text'` should make it ignore that content type if i'm reading the docs correctly.  So I'm out of ideas, :s

Answer (score 0):

First try to catch the error by rewriting your ajax call as (See the error callback function).

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8181/rest/stuff',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
             alert('Success!');      
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
             console.log(jqXHR);
             console.log(exception);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I see this in this in the console: 
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(), 9 more… }  script.js:70:6
error  script.js:71:6

Comment: First, is there a second?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I see two things, the first with the Object {}, the second one only shows "error".

Comment: You are expecting a json data in front end, have you done **json encode** before returning your value to the front end.